# Double cosets and irreducibe representations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G=S_n$ be the usual permutation group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Suppose there are $d$ double cosets $H/G\backslash H$, labeled $K_a$ with $1\le a\le d$.

Suppose $G$ has $R$ irreducible representations, with characters $\chi_i$ with $1\le i\le R$.

We can define the average values $$\omega_i(g)=\frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{h\in H}\chi_i(hg).$$ Using orthogonality of the characters, we see that $$\sum_{g\in G}\omega_i(g)\omega_j(g)=\frac{1}{|H|^2}\sum_{h_1,h_2\in H}\sum_{g\in G}\chi_i(h_1g)\chi_j(h_2g)\propto\frac{1}{|H|^2}\sum_{h_1,h_2\in H}\chi_i(h_1h_2^{-1})\delta_{ij}$$ is zero unless $i=j$. But, since these functions are obvisouly constant on double cosets, we can also write the above sum as $$\sum_{a=1}^d |K_a|\omega_i(K_a)\omega_j(K_a)\propto \delta_{ij}.$$ This is an orthogonality relation for the vectors $\vec{\omega_i}$ and $\vec{\omega_j}$.

My question is this. The vectors are $d$-dimensional and there are $R$ of them. If $R>d$, orthogonality is impossible for non-zero vectors. So some of them must vanish.

This is indeed the case, for example, if we take $H=G$, because then the $\omega_i$ are scalars but they all vanish except the one associated with the trivial representation.

My question is where can I learn more about this subject, really.

Comment: Huh? $d$ can be as little as $1$ or as large as $\left|G\right|$ if $H$ is chosen to be $G$ or $1$.

Comment: I don't see where the $∝$ sign comes from.

Comment: @darijgrinberg $\sum_{g\in G}\chi_i(h_1g)\chi_j(h_2g)\propto\delta_{ij}$, no?

Comment: Why? $\chi_i\left(h_i ?\right)$ (with the quotient mark being the variable) is not a character.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99480/discussion-between-thedude-and-darij-grinberg).